# market,market square, square

Tags: word-choice

can anyone tell me the difference between these words?
According to the dictionary these are

**market** is a place where buyers and sellers of a specific good or service interact with each other in order to facilitate an exchange.

**market square** -  a public marketplace where food and merchandise is sold

**square**- A rectangular space enclosed by streets and occupied by buildings

The question is, which one of above-mentioned words would fit in in this context?: "

In the autumn of 1941 the following policemen: Wacek, Lerek, Marecki, Zebryk and Żukowski, herded all of us to the *market*/*market square*/*square*. On our way to the *market*/*market square*/*square* some women warned us that we were in trouble. When we were on the *market**/*market square*/*square**, the Lida county commander and the SSmen surrounded us.

Answer (score 2):

"Square" can be any of the open areas between buildings.  It may have no specific function and should be considered a generic term.  A "market square" is therefore just one type of square.  In essence, it is a square designated for use as a market (though its use could certainly extend beyond that).  A "market" could be set up anywhere.  For instance, there are many markets in Italy that open up along a street (which is closed for the day).

In summary, a "market" and a "square" are two separate things.  Sometimes they happen to be in the same location, in which case that is a "market square".

For your provided example, I would suggest the use of "market square" the first time you mention it.  Once the characters arrive, I would refer to it only as "the square", since we (the readers) already know which square it is.

Answer (score 1):

Your definitions above are correct, so your choice really depends on what you're trying to convey. I think *market square* works best here because it's the most descriptive, indicating that it's an open public space normally used for commerce. A *square* by itself also works fine here, but is a little less descriptive, especially since a town might have multiple plazas (squares) in a small area, but usually only one market square in a neighborhood. A *market* alone could be a synonym for a grocery store, and isn't necessarily an open space where you could herd people like a market square.